# npm run dev throw an ENOENT error when i write run command npm run dev then this error display

Tags: javascript, node.js, npm, webpack

When I run `npm run dev` command then this error display in terminal. So can help me in desire error

`dev` script

```bash
"dev": "npm run development"
```

`development` script

```bash
"development": "cross-env NODE_ENV=development node_modules/webpack/bin/webpack.js --progress --config=node_modules/laravel-mix/setup/webpack.config.j"
```

````
The system cannot find the path specified.
node:events:491
      throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
      ^

Error: spawn node_modules\webpack\bin\webpack.js ENOENT
    at notFoundError (C:\Users\awfte\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\cross-env\node_modules\cross-spawn\lib\enoent.js:6:26)
    at verifyENOENT (C:\Users\awfte\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\cross-env\node_modules\cross-spawn\lib\enoent.js:40:16)
    at ChildProcess.cp.emit (C:\Users\awfte\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\cross-env\node_modules\cross-spawn\lib\enoent.js:27:25)
    at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (node:internal/child_process:291:12)
Emitted 'error' event on ChildProcess instance at:
    at ChildProcess.cp.emit (C:\Users\awfte\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\cross-env\node_modules\cross-spawn\lib\enoent.js:30:37)
    at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (node:internal/child_process:291:12) {
  code: 'ENOENT',
  errno: 'ENOENT',
  syscall: 'spawn node_modules\\webpack\\bin\\webpack.js',
  path: 'node_modules\\webpack\\bin\\webpack.js',
  spawnargs: [
    '--progress',
    '--config=node_modules/laravel-mix/setup/webpack.config.j'
  ]
}```
````

Comment: Did you have the dev script in the package.json file?

Comment: Have you webpack isntalled?